# Why does $\mbox{Irr}(\alpha,K)$ have distinct roots in $N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

My textbook assumes that

1. $N\supset K$ is normal and finite
2. $\alpha\in N$ is separable over $K$
3. $N\supset K(\alpha)$ is separable

and deduces (in order to prove that $N\supset K$ is separable) that $\newcommand{\Irr}{\mbox{Irr}}\Irr(\alpha,K)$ has all its roots and all distinct in $N$.

I see why $N$ must contain all roots, since $N\supset K$ is normal. Also I see why $\alpha$ is NOT repeated as it is separable over $K$.

But how can I see that none of the other roots can be repeated roots?

Comment: If $\beta$ is a root of that polynomial, there is an automorphism with $\alpha\mapsto \beta$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: So is it because then with $f=\Irr(\alpha,K)$ we may write $$f=(X-\alpha)\cdots(X-\beta)$$ and apply your automorhpism $\varphi(\alpha)=\beta$ to get $$\varphi_*(f)=(X-\beta)\cdots(X-\varphi(\beta))$$ which is irreducible over $K$, so it must be the defining polynomial of $\beta$ thus of $\alpha$ since they are conjugate, showing that $\beta$ is only to be found in one bracket in $f=\varphi_*(f)$?

Comment: Please avoid defining new LaTeX commands in the title. It affects the entire page. (And just for `\operatorname{Irr}` or `\mbox` or `\text`, I don't even see the point in having a new command anyway... I mean, you only used it twice in the entire post.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ok, sorry about that. I had no idea. I did not know when initiating the post that I would only write it twice, much less was I aware that it would impose strange behavior on the entire page. I have removed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. If it has a repeated root ($\alpha$ or another root - makes no difference), then that multiple root $\beta$ gives rise
to a common factor $(x-\beta)$ of $m(x)$ and $m'(x)$.

But by Euclid's algorithm $r(x):=\gcd(m(x),m'(x))\in K[x]$. This is thus a non-trivial factor of $m(x)$ contradicting the assumption that $m(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ as a minimal polynomial. Unless $r(x)=m(x)$, which in turn would imply $m'(x)=0$, which in turn implies that all the zeros of $m(x)$ have multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: It makes sense! But then the assumptions cited where not relevant to this particular point in the proof, right?

Comment: Well, you need to know that one of the roots of $m(x)$ is simple. Otherwise all the roots could have multiplicity $p=char K$, when $m'(x)=0$.